# Xamarin - Designer does not load

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, designer

I am trying to create a new Xamarin (blank app) project, and when I am opening the file "Main.axml" I get this error:

[image]

The error-text inside this "messagebox" is this:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: o 
>   at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIUnknownForObjectNative(Object
>   o, Boolean onlyInContext)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.UpdateD3DImageFromSharedSurface()
>   in
>   E:\A_work\102\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:line
>   140    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.RenderDesignerItemVisual(DesignerItem
>   item) in
>   E:\A_work\102\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:line
>   131    at
>   Xamarin.Designer.Windows.WpfSurfaceRenderer.QueueRender(DesignerItem
>   item) in
>   E:\A_work\102\s\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.Windows\WpfSurfaceRenderer.cs:line
>   361    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSurface.HandleSessionImageChanged(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\A_work\102\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSurface.cs:line
>   229    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.OnImageChanged() in
>   E:\A_work\102\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line
>   2037    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.HandleRendered(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\A_work\102\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line
>   1284
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
>   exceptionObject)

I found several topics through google that talk about the same issue, but either none of them explain if and how they solve the issue, or he solution was not working. If someone has encounter this error, it would be great to give me the solution for it.

EDIT: I use:
**1)** Visual Studio Community 2017 - Version 15.6.6   **2)** JDK Version: 1.8.0_171  **3)** Xamarin Version: 4.9.0.753 **4)** Xamarin Designer Version: 4.10.96

Comment: Can you please include your version information including the JDK version you're using?

Comment: @JonDouglas You are right. I edited my answer and I added the additional information. Tell me if I need to add something else as well.

Comment: Is this a x32 bit or x64 bit JDK 1.8?

Comment: @JonDouglas it is a x64 bit JDK (I downloaded that since I have an x64 bit computer).